# Test each method : Using Jest / enzyme for REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

How could I implement the right unit test for both methods . I tried to run a few things but I dont think is calling the method the correct way

```
 componentDidMount () {
this.setState({
  defaultData: this.props.defaultData
})
}

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
this.setState({
  defaultData: nextProps.defaultData
})
```

}

Could I implement something  along these lines for calling methods for example ? The test passes at the moment but i don't think is checking the method

```
 it (' ComponentWillReceiveProps : should return correct', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...baseProps } />);  
  wrapper.setState({test: 'test'});
  expect(wrapper.instance().componentWillReceiveProps('test')).toEqual();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend shallow testing but here is an example :

```
...
componentWillMount() {
    this.logUserId(this.props.userId);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.userId !== nextProps.userId) {
        this.logUserId(nextProps.userId);
    }
}
logUserId(userId) {
    console.log(userId);
}
...

import SomeComponent from ‘./SomeComponent’;
import { shallow } from ‘enzyme’;
describe('componentWillReceiveProps()', () => {
    it('call logUserId once', () => {
        const logUserId =
           sinon.stub(SomeComponent.prototype, ‘logUserId’);
        let userId = '123';
        const component = shallow(<SomeComponent userId={userId}/>;
// resetting call count from componentWillMount()
        logUserId.reset();
userId = '456';
        // triggers componentWillReceiveProps
        component.setProps({ userId });
// PASS!
        expect(logUserId).to.be.calledOnce.and.calledWith(userId); 
    })
})
```

taken from [link](https://medium.com/@tjhubert/react-enzyme-testing-componentwillreceiveprops-the-clean-way-4dba4f02be0b)

Comment: I will try it in a sec, what would  you recommend instead

Comment: Full Rendering (mount(...)) , its real test for how your component works

Comment: I never wrote anything with SINON before , i dont think i have it at the moment

Comment: forget about the SINON , you can do this with jest.mock, also with simulate of enzyme  , its the same

Comment: also again, i recommend to do mount test , and not to test life cycle function of react , but a real scenarios if your component